# Android - encryption and decryption

Tags: android, encryption

I am downloading apk by HTTPurlConnection and I am wondering, if there are possibilites of encryption on the side of the web and decryption after download with private and public keys. I know this was used in Windows Mobile smartphones, but is is possible to do the same with Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use secure HTTP (HTTPS) instead? No need to mess about with keys, and it will encrypt the download for you.

The problem with using your own keys is the decryption key will be in your app, and very easily accessible to anyone who wants to decrypt the stream - it's never going to be that secure as Android apps are relatively easy to reverse-engineer (Proguard obfuscation will help a bit)

Comment: If it were me I'd challenge that requirement - the extra cost of buying and installing an HTTPS certificate on the web server is likely to be lower than the effort required to build your own encryption method

Comment: Ok, I try to push on them, but on the other hand, does Android have some simple API for handling enryption and decryption?

Comment: Yes, here's a sample for encrypting strings that you can modify for binary data streams http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml